# How do I paginate in Laravel using Oracle Result Set (NOT using Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

I retrieved a dataset to a table and would like to limit results to 15 per page.  I'm not using Eloquent so the DB::table('users')->paginate(15); won't work for me.  Thanks

My data is from an Oracle database, which I'm new to. I just need a basic working example relevant to Laravel and PHP7.

Comment: This is *way* too broad. There's no such thing as a simple pagination system. Even eloquent's has a ton going on under the hood, including basic query using `offset` and `limit`, returning chunks, determining paging logic, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I didn't mean a simple system, I should have been clearer with my question.  I want to see an example In terms of making that pagination call within Laravel using PHP to an Oracle database.  How would you set that up in the controller pointing to, for example, a MyOracleResults class which holds that data I'm querying.  I hope I'm asking the right way this time.  If not, I appreciate your response regardless.

Comment: Sorry, that's still too broad. In Laravel, you would simply use `DB::table('whatever')->paginate(...);`, as you've shown. Laravel adapts to the DB system being used, so that `->paginate()`, and all other DB methods work for all DB systems, as the syntax varies between systems.

Comment: Ok thank you Tim.  Have a great day and may God bless you for your help.